# Selecting the most recent date, where a name matches?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'd like to search a spreadsheet for a name, and pick out the most recent date next to it if possible please? My data looks a little like:

```
|      Name      |     Date         |
|----------------|------------------|
|      Sally     |     04/06/2017   |
|----------------|------------------|
|      Tim       |     12/04/2018   |
|----------------|------------------|
|      Sally     |     16/09/2019   |
|----------------|------------------|
|      Sally     |     29/02/2018   |
```

In this case, I'd like to return `12/04/2018` for Tim, and `16/09/2019` for Sally.

Is this possible please?

**Update:** still struggling with this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(VLOOKUP(QUERY(
 {ROW(Events!A2:A), SORT(Events
!A2:D)},
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2 label max(Col1)''", 0), 
 {ROW(Events!A2:A), SORT(Events!A2:D)},
 {2, 3},
 0), 1, 0))
```

The dates are `Events!A` and the names are `Events!D` for what it's worth.

Comment: FYI `29/02/2018` is not a valid date

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(VLOOKUP(QUERY(
 {ROW(B2:B), SORT(A2:B)},
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2 label max(Col1)''", 0), 
 {ROW(B2:B), SORT(A2:B)},
 {2, 3},
 0), 1, 0))
```

this kind of creates a new virtual array in a virtual column which sorts that column with dates and with the rest of the data feeds **`QUERY`** which is returned in **`VLOOKUP`** consisting of columns **`2`** and **`3`** (virtual column 1 is omitted) and lastly output gets sorted by column **`1`** and **`0`** indicates that sorting is descending (1 would be ascending)

[image]

---

**european syntax:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(VLOOKUP(QUERY(
 {ROW(B2:B) \ SORT(A2:B)};
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2 label max(Col1)''"; 0); 
 {ROW(B2:B) \ SORT(A2:B)};
 {2 \ 3};
 0); 1; 0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks perfect, but I'm struggling to get it working. Specifically the formula outputs N/A, and I'm noticing that it keeps changing `SORT(Events!C2:A)` to `SORT(Events!A2:C)` for no reason, even if I clear the formula and start again :(

Comment: A2:C is valid syntax not C2:A. other than that I cant help you further unless you provide a copy of your sheet or at least mention which columns you had dedicated for this

Comment: Thank you so much, I've updated the original post -  the date column is Events!A and the names column is Events!D.

I'm looking up the vlookup query function right now but I'm struggling to get to grips with it, sorry :(

Comment: @Nick try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(VLOOKUP(QUERY(
 {ROW(Events!D2:D), SORT(Events!A2:D)},
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2 label max(Col1)''", 0), 
 {ROW(Events!D2:D), SORT(Events!A2:D)},
 {2, 5},
 0), 1, 0))`